# Por que no puedo mostrar el código de salida? en BASH

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
      
clear
if [ -f $@ ]   
then 
    echo "$@ Es un archivo"        
    exit 0                  
elif [ -d $@ ]        
then     
    echo "$@ Es un directorio"
    exit 1   
else    
    echo    "$@ Esto que mierda es?"
    exit 2    
fi    

echo "El codigo de salida es $?"
```

Ya sé que el script es un poco absurdo, pero es un ejercicio en el que me pedían que se mostrase el codigo de salida por cada condicional y no lo consigo!!! **Sabe alguien decirme por que no se muestra el cógido de salida de la última línea??**

Aquí el ejercicio en cuestión..
Write a shell script that accepts a file or directory name as an argument. Have the script report if it is a regular file, a directory, or other type of file. If it is a regular file, exit with a 0 exit status. If it is a directory, exit with a 1 exit status. If it is some other type of file, exit with a 2 exit status.

Comment: Estás haciendo exit en todas las condiciones de los if. No hace falta que pongas esos exit, ya que el código lo puedes imprimir al final. Ordena mejor el código para que sea legible y verás que no son necesarios

Comment: dale formato al código usando [edit]. Luego pega el código en http://shellcheck.net para las validaciones, así como explica lo que quieres hacer en lugar de solamente pegar código

Comment: @Jakala tengo que ponerlos, por que necesito un código distinto por cada if y no un código de salida "general" por así decirlo..

Comment: Entonces puedes asignar ese estado a una variable, y al final del codigo imprimirlo.

Comment: Gracias, no había caído en esa solución...